# Zero out rest of array row when 0 or lower is true

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an MxN array. I want to zero out all the values after an element in a row is zero or less.

For example the 2x12 array

```
111110011111
112321341411
```

should turn into

```
111110000000
112321341411
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of something you have tried already. And are you using a `numpy` array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not be the most efficient method, but I've used np.cumsum for these types of things.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> dat = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1], ])

>>> dat[np.cumsum(dat <= 0, 1, dtype='bool')] = 0

>>> print(dat)
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1]])
```

---

@Jaime just pointed out that, `np.logical_or.accumulate(dat <= 0, axis=1)`, is probably better than np.cumsum.

Comment: Originally I forgot that you can specify dtype in cumsum. I updated the answer to include this. It's probably a pretty efficient approach this way.

Comment: Nice use of boolean indexing, +1. Although the result is the same, I think it is a little more proper to compute the boolean mask as `np.logical_or.accumulate(dat <= 0, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you or someone else need alternative solution without using numpy.

```
>>> dat = ['111110011111','112321341411','000000000000', '123456789120']
>>> def zero(dat):
    result = []
    for row in dat:
        pos = row.find('0')
        if pos > 0:
            result.append(row[0:pos] + ('0' * (len(row) - pos)))
        else:
            result.append(row)
    return result

>>> res = zero(dat)
>>> res
['111110000000', '112321341411', '000000000000', '123456789120']
>>> dat
['111110011111', '112321341411', '000000000000', '123456789120']
```